# How to validate LinkedIn public profile url regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I jus want to validate the linkedin public profile url. I tried the concept like below

```
 a = "https://in.linkedin.com/afadasdf"
 p = re.compile('(http(s?)://|[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.|[linkedin])[linkedin/~\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9/~\-_,&=\?\.;]+[^\.,\s<]')
 p.match(a)
```

The above concept is working fine. But when i give the url **https://www.linkedin.com** means that it's not working. Can anyone help me to validate both concepts.

Comment: Your pattern starts with ``(http(s?)://|[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.|[linkedin])``, so I think it will match http or www or linkedin, but not www.linkedin...

Comment: I've been using this: `^(http(s?)://)?([\w\d\-\_]*\.)?linkedin.com/[^.\s]*$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the oring between the http(s) and www. which has given you the above problem. You could change them to * (i.e. 0 or more).

```
import re

a = "https://www.linkedin.com/afadasdf"
p = re.compile('((http(s?)://)*([a-zA-Z0-9\-])*\.|[linkedin])[linkedin/~\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9/~\-_,&=\?\.;]+[^\.,\s<]')
print p.match(a)
```

Although you might want to restrict it to www rather than any numbers or letters? So maybe:

```
p = re.compile('((http(s?)://)*([www])*\.|[linkedin])[linkedin/~\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9/~\-_,&=\?\.;]+[^\.,\s<]')
```

Answer (score 1):

This pattern may help.

```
^((http|https):\/\/)?+(www.linkedin.com\/)+[a-z]+(\/)+[a-zA-Z0-9-]{5,30}+$
```

I have tested it and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of matching the url with a regex you could use the `urllib` module:

```
In [1]: import urllib
In [2]: u = "https://in.linkedin.com/afadasdf"
In [3]: urllib.parse.urlparse(u)
Out[3]: ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='in.linkedin.com', path='/afadasdf', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

Now you can check for the `netloc` and `path` property.

Comment: there are many possible "netloc" ar.linkedin.com jo.linkedin.com  etc